# Error missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when call method from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two Python files.

**second.py**:

```py
class Exame:
   def on(self):
      # Some Code here
   def tw(self):
      # some code run
```

**first.py:**

```py
from second.py import Exame
Exam.on()
```

In `first.py` when I call `on` method in `second.py` file I get error `"missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"`

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you mean: `e = Exame(); e.on()`?

Comment: `on` is an instance method, and you haven't created an instance.  Do `Exam().on()`, or `exam = Exam()` and then `exam.on()`.

Comment: Alternatively, define `on` as a class method or static method. If you don't know what these are, you should go through a tutorial on classes. Please read [how much research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953). Your question has already been asked and answered, you just need to google the error message.